# Usage of custom metric in hybrid analysis in sDNA

Tags: sdna

I would like to use a custom metric for the distance analysis in sDNA.

To this end, I use the following settings:

- Routing and analysis metric: 'Hybrid'
- Radii: same order of magnitude as the metric
- Radial metric: Custom or Hybrid (see below)
- Custom metric field: Empty
- Advanced config: lineformula = euc/FULLeuc*column_name

If I set the radial metric to **hybrid**, I receive the error message: 'ERROR: Error in formula for link metric'.

If I set the radial metric to **custom**, there is no change in the output values (e.g. betweenness remains the same, I assume because the same links are considered in the calculation).

The purpose of the custom metric is to reward/penalize more/less attractive links in the calculation of metrics.

My example network can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/on6g1jg4vzaa3mu/example_network.gdb.zip?dl=0).

Software:
ArcGIS 10.5.1
sDNA+ 3.4.5

Comment: I went over the manual in more detail and found the answer in section 7 [link](https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_4_5/guide_to_individual_tools.html). In the advanced config the _radlineformula_ (hybrid analysis) or the _radcustommetric_ (custom metric) needs to be set instead of the lineformula.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is correct in his comment; for hybrid *radial* metrics then `radlineformula` and `radjuncformula` must be set in advanced config. For hybrid *analytical* metrics the equivalents are `lineformula` and `juncformula`. This allows use of different metrics for the radius and routing/analysis which is useful more often than you'd think, to make results more interpretable - see [this paper](https://www.tropic.org.uk/~crispin/research/spatial%20localization%20of%20closeness%20and%20betweenness%20contradictions%20accepted.pdf).

Alternatively set the radial metric to `MATCH_ANALYTICAL` and then you only need to set `lineformula` and `juncformula`.

Custom metrics are something altogether simpler, they read a single data field off each link rather than an expression. You need to provide the appropriate field name in the configuration dialog; if not then it assumes all links have the same metric (=1) which gives you topological analysis.